# PHP DOM saveHTML changes formatting

Tags: php, html, dom

I load external HTML page and with loadHTML.

Than I replace two childs and remove one.

saveHTML() method changes something and I do not want that.

It changes position of the closing

```
</head>
```

tag, puts it right after  and on original page closing head is further down the line after few tags.

It also changes body tag to:

```
<body class="something">
```

to just

```
<body>
```

.

How I can save it using PHP DOM so it respects all the positioning and attributes?
Here is the code:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
@$document->loadHTML($contents);

$login_signup = $document->getElementById('loginBar')->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(1);
$login_signup->removeChild($login_signup->getElementsByTagName('h3')->item(0));

$todays_a = $document->createElement('a', 'Todays Digest');
$todays_a->setAttribute('href', $domain . $digest_newsletter . date('mdy') . '.html');

$previous_a = $document->createElement('a', 'Previous Digest');
$previous_a->setAttribute('href', $domain . $digest_newsletter . date('mdy', strtotime('-1 day')) . '.html');

$todays_div = $document->getElementById('myDiv');
$todays_div->replaceChild($todays_a, $todays_div->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0));

$previous_div = $document->getElementById('myDiv2');
$previous_div->replaceChild($previous_a, $previous_div->getElementsByTagName('script')->item(0));

$contents = $document->saveHTML($document);
```

Comment: Sorry bad formatting on my part. So it puts "head" tag right after closing "title" tag. Even though closing "head" tag is further down the lines.

Comment: it doesn't work? wheres the codes?